# Can AppConfig.label be used to import modules from an app?

Tags: django, django-models, django-apps

I have a third party app I have set up in a subdirectory:

```
# myproject/vendor/rock_n_roll/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig

class RockNRollConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'rock_n_roll'
    label = 'rockme'
    verbose_name = "Rock ’n’ roll"
```

Now, when I import this I can use `from vendor.rock_n_roll.models import ...`. However, I can't seem to use the label in the same way. E.g. `from rockme.models import ...` results in "module not found".

[Per the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/) the `AppConfig.label` is unique across the whole project, and I assume is a shorthand way to access the app. Have I misunderstood the purpose? Is there a way to simply use the `label` as the import path?

If not, what is the purpose of the `label` otherwise for?

Comment: You can't import like this, `from rockme.models import` because **`rockme`** isn't a [***python module***](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).

Comment: Also, I feel the Django doc for the [`AppConfig.label`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.label) is self explanatory

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Thanks, unfortunately the docs don't say how or why `AppConfig.Label` is used. Could you give an example? What's its purpose practically when developing an app?

Comment: have you registered your app in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` ?

Comment: @Subham yes, as `vendor.rock_n_roll.apps.RocknRollConfig`